# Need a way around XMLHttpRequest preflight problem

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access climate data from the [USDA webservice](https://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/web_service/AWDB_Web_Service_Reference.htm), which seems to have a broken OPTIONS configuration.  Doubly unfortunate, firefox wants to "preflight" all of my GET requests into OPTIONS and I don't know how to make it stop!

I've boiled my request down to the bare minimum.

```
var url=" https://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services";
var async=true;
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

But annoyingly, firefox seems to be automatically filling out quite a number of other headers by itself, then detecting that they are "[forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)", and forcing the preflight anyway!  Frustrating!

Here are all the headers that go out in the OPTIONS:

```
Host: www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin
Origin: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

(Note that if I right-click the transaction in web developer, do "edit and resend", change the method from OPTIONS to GET, these headers work just fine.  Thus my claim that the government server is misconfigured.)

Now, my question is, is there a way to do any of the following:

1. tell the browser to do the GET directly and skip the preflight "logic"
2. tell the browser not to add the forbidden headers
3. remove the forbidden headers from the request prior to sending

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't that is how CORS works. The browser asks if it can access the info and the server has to say yes or now.

Comment: `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` this will guarantee triggerning preflight ... do not use RESPONSE headers in REQUEST

Comment: However, in this case, it's not that `www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov` has a *broken OPTIONS configuration* - the issue is that `www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov` doesn't allow CORS ... **at all** - proxy the request through *your own server*, and you'll be golden

Comment: `do "edit and resend"` ... when you edit and resend from the network panel, it's no longer subject to CORS permissions

Comment: Jaromanda X nailed it.  Guess I misunderstood the meaning of the header. Post as an answer and I'll be sure to give you credit.

Once that was off the plate I noticed that "edit and resend" was actually making TWO requests, the second, working one, to a different domain.  Tweak the url and things work fine! Can't believe I wasted all day on something so simple!